# Using System.Runtime.InteropServices but HandleRef is not found

Tags: c#, build, namespaces, interop, swig

I'm trying to use Swig to wrap Raknet for use with Unity, but I can't build the generated C# files because I have 2,300+ errors saying:

```
The type or namespace name 'HandleRef' could not be found
```

From what I can tell, HandleRef is a struct in the "System.Runtime.InteropServices" namespace. However, I definitely have the statement

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

at the top of the appropriate files. Additionally, I have mscorlib in my References.

I'm extremely confused as to what's going wrong. Am I doing this wrong? Is there some factor I'm missing? How can I get this to build?

(I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 on Windows 8, if that makes any difference.)

Comment: What does your client profile look like?  If your main form is set to, ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile", have you tried setting it to ".Net Framework 4" instead?

Comment: I'm not sure how to set/view that. After googling it, though, it looks like Visual Studio Express 2012 doesn't let you modify the target/client profile. :(

Comment: Isn't it listed in the project properties?

Comment: Where should I look? I can't find it.

Comment: You and change it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I don't have that version of visual studio. Additionally, the version I'm using is 4.5, which according to the docs should have HandleRef.

Comment: There are two versions of Express.  One to make apps for the Windows Store, another to make traditional desktop apps.  High odds that you got the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem

I found that generating the c# files with an older version of Swig (2.0.1 specifically) worked much better with RakNet.